# how to get the only file names from the folder in java8

Tags: java, file, java-8

I am want to list out the only file names from the folder in Java 8. I have tried this code, but it is giving me the complete path.

```
try {
    List<java.nio.file.Path> files      = Files.list(new   File("F://csv/").toPath())
                .filter(p -> !p.getFileName()
                .toString().startsWith("."))
                .limit(3)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Path::getFileName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileName--) to get the file name from a path:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(Paths.get("f:/csv"))
                             .filter(...)
                             .limit(...)
                             .map(Path::getFileName)
                             .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Note: You should close the Stream returned by `Files.list` so it should be in a try-with-resources.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this one, Change your path in File Variable like C:\DIR

```
 File folder = new File("Dir path");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println( listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } 
       }
```

Comment: i want to implement in java 8, this is prior to java 8.please tell me in java 8

Comment: @BodapatiSrinu the term you should use is 'Functional'

Comment: Functional in the sense in java8,can you brief about it @sidgate

Comment: @Misha if use this code i am getting error like (The type Path does not define getFileName(Path) that is applicable here)  at                                                                            
                             .map(Path::getFileName)